# Програмно изменить стиль вывода

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf

С помощью JSF выводится элемент SelectManyMenu, источник заполнения - ArrayList, каждому стрингу в БД соответствует булевый флаг. Требуется, при заполнении элемента, проверять флаг в бине и, при положительном значении, придавать стрингу назначать стиль (например жирный текст).

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="person" value="#{sB.selectedPersons}"
    style="width:300px;height:230px" showCheckbox="true"
                filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" scrollHeight="200">
    <f:selectItems value="#{sB.persons}" var="person" 
                itemLabel="#{person}" itemValue="#{person}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":fltfrm:hperson :datfrm" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Возможно ли реализовать такое на JS/JQuery/jstl+css?  Если да, то как? Интересует именно front end часть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже тестовый пример с подсветкой красным цветом уволенных сотрудников. Класс Person:

```
public class Person {

  private String name;
  private boolean dismissed;

  public Person(String name, boolean dismissed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dismissed = dismissed;
  }
//get/set методы
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

  public ArrayList<Person> getPersons() {
    ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new Person("Иванов", false));
    result.add(new Person("Петров", true));
    result.add(new Person("Смирнов", false));
    result.add(new Person("Сидоров", false));
    return result;
  }
}
```

Страница:

```
        <p:selectOneMenu var="person">
            <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.persons}" var="person" itemLabel="#{person.name}" itemValue="#{person}"/>

            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" style="#{person.dismissed ? 'color: red' : ''}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:selectManyMenu var="person">
            <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.persons}" var="person" itemLabel="#{person.name}" itemValue="#{person}"/>

            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" style="#{person.dismissed ? 'color: red' : ''}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:selectManyMenu>

        <p:dataList var="person" value="#{testBean.persons}">
            <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" style="#{person.dismissed ? 'color: red' : ''}"/>
        </p:dataList>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `var` должен быть указан и в `p:selectOneMenu` и в `f:selectItems`. Не используйте `String` в качестве элемента списка, т.к. в этом случае `p:column` [будет проигнорирован](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740430/1341148).

Comment: Спасибо, ваш пример работает, это то, что надо.  Но, пытаюсь сделать то же самое для <p:dataList и пока не получается.

Comment: <p:dataList value="#{uB.users}" var="users" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                Пользователи
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{users.name} " style="#{user.kMark > 0 ? 'color: red' : ''}"/>
        </p:dataList>

Comment: Я дополнил страницу в примере, в т.ч. добавил p:selectManyMenu как в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Для p:dataList тоже работает в выше приведенном коде синтаксическая ошибка, вместо value="#{user**s**.name} надо user.name