# Учитывать доп. признак у строки

Tags: java, архитектура, проектирование, jsf, структуры-данных

Есть метод, который в цикле заполняет List элементами из ДБ. У элементов в ДБ есть дополнительный boolean признак, в зависимости от значения которого меняется front end представление этой строки `style="#{katmark ? 'font-weight: bold' : ''}"`

Вопрос в следующем, так как используется List, как привязать булево значение к строке?  Ведь в лист его не поместить...

Comment: ну так вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - к стрингу его не прикрутить. никакие фокусы тут не помогут, от стринга не унаследуешься и ничего не переопределишь. и лист - это по сути массив.в рамкахтаких условий решения нет. но вариантов довольно много. затолкайте свой стринг не в лист, а в мапу, где значение - булеан. или воспользуйтесь классом pair и в него толкайте стринг и булеан, а уже см экземпляр в лист, или сами создайте свой класс и его толкайте в лист.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут, по-моему, возможны два довольно очевидных решения:

1. Добавлять к строке (например, в начало) специальный сивол для обозначения признака, проверять этот символ при форматировании, а перед использованием строки удалять;
2. Хранить в списке не строки, а специальные объекты, содержащие как саму строку, так и этот признак.

Смотря по вашей ситуации, может быть можно также в списке строку хранить уже вместе с форматированием, или завести отдельное множество (в смысле `Set`), куда добавлять строки, нуждающиеся в особом форматировании.

Comment: Вот пример для п.п. 2: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758065/183597